# Enable system extension without UI access

Tags: macos, command-line, security

I'm trying to set up a program on a CI with a system extension without access to the UI.

The main problem is the server is wiped between runs, so I can't configure this program beforehand. I tried using cliclick and creating a program to mimic mouse/keyboard input to mimic the manual process, but this also requires accepting a permission on the Mac UI (to allow the terminal to control the computer).

Is there any way to enable a system extension on the command line without using the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS is designed to not allow this remotely. There are several instances where you need to be at the Mac for some boot level updates and then again need a trusted graphical session to opt in to setup and consent dialogs.

Some of this can be scripted with a MDM and pushing management and configuration profiles.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/system-extensions-payload-settings-dep5d1584ca4/web

Even that requires users to opt in to the MDM configuration in many instances. Do you purchase enough Macs to have an Apple rep or business relationship?